# Why is my razor @if not evaluating correctly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

Why does my `@if` statement not evaluate to true correctly? Given the razor code below:

```
@{
    List<string> list = new List<string> { "test 0", "test 1" };

    int index = 0;
}
@foreach (var item in list)
{
    <div index="@index" item="@if (index == 0) { <text>zero</text> }">
        @item
    </div>
    index++;
}
```

produces this output:

```
<div index="0" item="">
    test 0
</div>
<div index="1" item="">
    test 1
</div>
```

desired output:

```
<div index="0" item="zero">
    test 0
</div>
<div index="1" item="">
    test 1
</div>
```

the text `zero` never gets rendered, placing a breakpoint on the div tag, shows `index 2` on both iterations(!). I know this is probably something really obvious I am missing but I can't figure out what that is.

Update: this makes no difference

```
<div index="@index" item="@if (index == 0)
                              {
                                  <text>zero</text>
                              }">
    @item
</div>
```

Comment: Try `item="@(index == 0 ? 'zero' : '')">`

Comment: @SteveGreene that works, but why doesn't regular old `@if` work in this case? Is it just bad syntax?

Comment: I prefer ternary for inline operations like this. I use `@if` with brackets to conditionally render an entire tag (div/input/span/etc).

Comment: Actually what your code should output is <div index="0" item="<text>zero</text>">. Maybe it knows a tag shouldn't go into a property value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is "by-design" as demonstrated here: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/9070

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@{
   List<string> list = new List<string> { "test 0", "test 1" };
   int index = 0;
}
@foreach (var item in list)
{
    if(index == 0){
    <div index="@index" item="zero">
        @item
        </div>
        index++;
    }
    else if(index == 1)
    {
        <div index="@index" item="">
        @item
        </div>
        index++;
    }
    else
    {
        // more here
    }
}
```

I think maybe your brackets just were in the wrong place. This seemed to work for me here... https://dotnetfiddle.net/BohydN (only the right half of the grid is relevant).

Comment: There are lots of ways around this, but my question is why?

Comment: Sorry, I am not entirely sure. I just noticed that the brackets looked to be in the wrong place upon looking at it and tested to see if moving them into a different order would resolve the problem. The "why" would be the brackets are in the wrong place, but the "why does that matter"... well, maybe someone can answer this for both of us...